# Dashed down arrow

Tags: arrows

I am looking for a solution for **dashed down arrow**. Have already tried packages like `lucidabr` and `MnSymbol`, but these turn my whole stuff upside down, producing a lot errors like

> "*Something is not ok in line XY*".

I have also tried `\rotatebox` for `\dashrightarrow` (which is available in `ams`), and it just didn't do neither the rotation nor the placing..

I was thinking, maybe the best if I can produce it for myself.

Any help?

Comment: Can we see the symbol in context? How should the symbol behave like (an relational symbol, a binary operator)? Where should the baseline be?

Comment: Yes, I want it in context like '$\alpha:a|b$' where this $|$ should be the dashed downarrow..

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Basic Solution:

Now sure exactly what problem you had with using `\rotatebox`, but it seems to work if used as `\rotatebox{-90}{$\dashrightarrow$}`:

[image]

### Notes:

- Depending on the actual application this might need to be raised vertically, and that can be down with `\raisebox`:

  ```
    \newcommand{\dashdownarrow}{\raisebox{2.0ex}{\rotatebox{-90}{$\dashrightarrow$}}}
  ```
- If it is a binary/relational operator than you can enclose the symbol in `\mathbin{}/\mathrel{}`:

  ```
    \newcommand{\dashdownarrow}{\mathbin{\raisebox{2.0ex}{\rotatebox{-90}{$\dashrightarrow$}}}}
  ```

---

### Use `\mathchoice` to  auto resize:

As per Gonzalo Medina 's suggestion, to be able to use this for different math sizes such as in subscripts, you can use `\mathchoice` to ensure that the symbol also adjusts in size depending on the surrounding math environment:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\newcommand\dashdownarrowi{\mathchoice%
    {\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\displaystyle\dashrightarrow$}}%
    {\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\displaystyle\dashrightarrow$}}%
    {\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\scriptstyle\dashrightarrow$}}%
    {\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\scriptscriptstyle\dashrightarrow$}}%
} 

\newcommand{\dashdownarrow}{\mathrel{\dashdownarrowi}} 

\begin{document} 
    $A\dashdownarrow B\quad M_{A\dashdownarrow B}\quad L_{M_{A\dashdownarrow B}}$ 
\end{document}
```

---

### Use `\text{}` for auto resizing (and change size):

egreg had provided a simpler way to get the same effect and that is by enclosing the symbol in `\text{}`, allows it to re size appropriately:

[image]

### Notes:

- In this version I added `\scalebox` so that you can make the symbol smaller -- adjust the scale factor to suit.
- If you desire to move it vertically you can use `\raisebox{<length>}{}`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\newcommand\ddaaux{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\scalebox{0.70}{$\dashrightarrow$}}} 
\newcommand\dashdownarrow{\mathrel{\text{\ddaaux}}}

\begin{document} 
    $A\dashdownarrow B\quad M_{A\dashdownarrow B}\quad L_{M_{A\dashdownarrow B}}$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or `\newcommand\dashdownarrow{\mathrel{\mathpalette\ddaaux\relax}}` and then `\newcommand\ddaaux[2]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$#1\dashrightarrow$}}`

Comment: Or, with `amsmath`, `\newcommand\dashdownarrow{\mathrel{\text{\ddaaux}}}`
and `\newcommand\ddaaux{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\dashrightarrow$}}`

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try these all..
@Peter: I would prefer a bit smaller arrow, if possible.

Comment: @egreg: Ingenious!!  Don't think I have seen that trick before.  Will update solution for egreg's suggestion, and also smaller arrow.

Comment: Well, for me, it's **not rotating** the right arrow but places it in a very odd place:( Is it possible that the *xdvi* viewer is the faulty?

Comment: @Berci Yes, that's probably the reason. Why aren't you using `pdflatex`?

Comment: .. or the .dvi file somehow.. Now I have generated a .pdf, and it works!

Comment: I am used to simple latex and .dvi... It's an issue then about the *latex* compiler itself and with rotatebox, no?

Comment: Got it. Smaller. Perfect. Continue with .pdf, thank you:)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina `\mathpalette` requires two arguments. See ["The mysteries of `\mathpalette`"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/4427)

Answer (score 4):

A solution that creates the missing symbols using `\rotatebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dashdownarrow}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\dasharrow@vert{-90}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\dashuparrow}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\dasharrow@vert{90}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\dasharrow@vert}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$#1\vcenter{}$}%
  \sbox2{$#1\dashrightarrow\m@th$}%
  \dimen@=1.2\dimexpr\ht2-\ht0\relax
  % 1/2 width of the new symbol with side bearing
  \sbox2{\raisebox{-\ht0}{\unhcopy2}}%
  \ht2=\z@
  \dp2=\z@
  \vcenter{\hbox to 2\dimen@{\hfill\rotatebox{#2}{\box2}\hfill}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  A \dashrightarrow B \dashdownarrow C \dashuparrow D \dashleftarrow E
\]
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}%
\[
  A \mathrel{\fbox{$\dashrightarrow$}}
  B \mathrel{\fbox{$\dashdownarrow$}}
  C \mathrel{\fbox{$\dashuparrow$}}
  D \mathrel{\fbox{$\dashleftarrow$}}
  E
\]
\[
  A\dashdownarrow B % \displaystyle and \textstyle have same size
  \qquad
  \scriptstyle A \dashdownarrow B
  \qquad
  \scriptscriptstyle A \dashdownarrow B
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The new symbols adapt to the current math style with the help of macro `\mathpalette`.
- `\m@th` sets `\mathsurround=0pt`, only needed if `\mathsurround (additional space around math formula) is different from zero (zero is the default).
- `\dashrightarrow` is centered around the math axis. The height of the math axis can be measured by an empty `\vcenter{}`.

Comment: This answer is moved from a duplicate [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/182714/16967).

Answer (score 1):

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\setmathfont{xits-math}
\[
a\downdasharrow b
\]
%\setmathfont{cambria math} % not available on my system
%\[
%a\downdasharrow b
%\]
\setmathfont{asana-math}
\[
a\downdasharrow b
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

And with the tips from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76239), you may define any other arrow for your needs:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand\ddaaux{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\scalebox{1}{$\rightdotarrow$}}} 
\newcommand\downdotarrow{\mathrel{\text{\ddaaux}}}
\newcommand\bkaux{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\scalebox{1}{$\rightbkarrow$}}} 
\newcommand\downbkarrow{\mathrel{\text{\bkaux}}}
\newcommand\dbkaux{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\scalebox{1}{$\dbkarow$}}} 
\newcommand\downdbkarrow{\mathrel{\text{\dbkaux}}}

\begin{document}
\setmathfont{xits-math}
\[
a\downdotarrow b; a\downbkarrow b; a\downdbkarrow b
\]
\setmathfont{asana-math}
\[
a\downdotarrow b; a\downbkarrow b; a\downdbkarrow b
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to fine-tune the scaling.

Comment: This answer is moved from a duplicate question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/182714.