# Commonly used arrows with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

In a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76062/to-arrow-with-tikz-or-tikzcd) Gonzalo Medina and Peter Grill gave a solution to replace the `\to` arrow by an arrow generated by `TikZ`.

For some people using TikZ in commutative diagrams, it would be perhaps desirable to uniformize the tips of some common arrows (`\to`, `\leftarrow`, `\mapsto`,`\rightsquigarrow`,etc.)

One can extend Peter Grill's solution in the question above (Gonzalo Medina's solution provides an arrow that resizes, but since arrows other than `\to` are less commonly used in super- or subindices, here the simplest solution is used) to obtain a`\leftarrow` as in the code show bellow. The problem is with the `\mapsto` arrow, for I cannot produce it: its vertical part is too large, as shown in the picture bellow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Tikz part
%********************************************************************
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,scopes}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{join/.code=\tikzset{after node path={%
\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)%
edge[every join]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}}
\makeatother
%
\tikzset{>=stealth',every on chain/.append style={join},
         every join/.style={->}}
\tikzstyle{labeled}=[execute at begin node=$\scriptstyle,
   execute at end node=$]
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{
commutative diagrams/.cd,
arrow style=math font,
diagrams={>=stealth}} 
%*******************************************************
%redefining the arrows
%*******************************************************
\newcommand{\MyOt}[1][]{\mathbin{\tikz \draw [#1, stealth-] (0,0) (0,0.5ex) -- (1.0em,0.5ex);}}
\newcommand{\MyTo}[1][]{\mathbin{\tikz \draw [-stealth, #1] (0,0) (0,0.5ex) -- (1.0em,0.5ex);}}
\newcommand{\MyMapsto}[1][]{\mathbin{\tikz \draw [|-stealth, #1] (0,0) (0,0.5ex) -- (1.0em,0.5ex);}}

\let\OldTo\to
\let\OldOt\leftarrow
\let\OldMapsto\mapsto
\renewcommand{\to}{\MyTo}%
\renewcommand{\leftarrow}{\MyOt}
\renewcommand{\mapsto}{\MyMapsto}
\newcommand{\where}{\quad\mbox{where}\quad}
%************************************************** 

\begin{document}    

\begin{align*}
f: A\to B & \quad \rightsquigarrow \quad f^*:A^*\leftarrow B^*\where  f^*:\phi \mapsto \phi\circ f\qquad&\mbox{(with TikZ)} \\
f: A\OldTo B &\quad \rightsquigarrow \quad f^*:A^*\OldOt B^* \!\!\where f^*:\phi \OldMapsto \phi\circ f\qquad &\mbox{(ordinary)}\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The result is: 
[image]

Comment: The arrows should be declared by `\mathrel`, not `\mathbin`

Comment: I just substituted `\mathbin` by `\mathrel`: same result.

Comment: Well, `\mathrel` or `\mathbin` influence the spacing around the arrows, not the arrows themselves. By the way, if I had to express a preference, I'd point to the second row.

Comment: Though, I'm a loyal TikZ foot soldier, I think such a replacement is only justified if the arrows are unquestionably prettier than the usual ones since it will bring a large overhead (unless you protocol or use the basic layer drawing commands etc.)

Comment: Well, people use TikZ for commutative diagrams: they look pretty nice with `stealth` (or similar) tips. I think that using uniform tips in all arrows doument would be nice for some people.  An example of this kind is http://www.ams.org/notices/200907/rtx090700809p.pdf. People use this arrows even if the commutative diags are absent, e.g. second page in  http://www.ams.org/notices/201210/rtx121001386p.pdf

Comment: @JorgeCampos I'm not questioning the use of TikZ. I'm just warning that the beauty vs. overhead must be justified at least :)

Comment: To fix the height of the `mapsto`, you could draw the vertical line yourself: `\newcommand{\MyMapsto}[1][]{\mathbin{\tikz \draw [-stealth, cap=round, #1] (0,0) (0,0.97ex) -- (0,0.035ex) (0,0.50ex) -- (1.0em,0.50ex);}}`. Might still need some more tweaking of the vertical line though.  I am not sure what you want to change regarding the `\rightsquigarrow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?  I put together a composite `\mapsto`, by adding a vertical rule to a stealth arrow (outside of tikz)  EDIT: Now it works in `\scriptstyle`

```
\documentclass{article}
% See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-
%            single-symbol-from-a-different-font
% Setup the matha font (from mathabx.sty)
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}

% Define a subset character from that font (from mathabx.dcl)
% to completely replace the \subset character, you can replace
% \varsubset with \subset

\DeclareMathSymbol{\varleftarrow}{3}{matha}{"D0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrightarrow}{3}{matha}{"D1}

\usepackage{scalerel}

\def\Newmapsto{%
  \mbox{$\displaystyle\rule{.3ex}{0ex}\rule[.2ex]{.075ex}{.8ex}\rule{-.8ex}{0ex}%
  \varrightarrow$}}%
\def\newmapsto{%
\scalerel*{\Newmapsto}{\scaleobj{1.2}{\mapsto}}%
}
\begin{document}
\[
A \mapsto B \qquad A \newmapsto B \scriptstyle \qquad 
A \mapsto B \qquad A \newmapsto B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Thanks to varsop for the very effective and simpler alternative using `\joinrel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
% See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-
%            single-symbol-from-a-different-font
% Setup the matha font (from mathabx.sty)
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\varleftarrow}{3}{matha}{"D0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrightarrow}{3}{matha}{"D1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mapstochar} {3}{matha}{"DE} 
\def\newmapsto{\mapstochar\joinrel\kern1.7pt\varrightarrow}

\begin{document}
\[
A \mapsto B \qquad A \newmapsto B \scriptstyle \qquad 
A \mapsto B \qquad A \newmapsto B
\]
\[
\scriptscriptstyle A \mapsto B \qquad A \newmapsto B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One can also achieve the same result without building a new vertical rule. Just perform the same steps as in the answer until `\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrightarrow}{3}{matha}{"D1}` and then add `\DeclareMathSymbol{\mapstochar}            {3}{matha}{"DE}` and moreover `\def\newmapsto{\mapstochar\joinrel\varrightarrow}`. 

`\joinrel` does the trick!

Comment: @varsop That is a very clever approach with which I was not familiar.  However, I note that, without some other adjustment, the placement of the vertical bar is not at the far end of the arrow, as it should be.  However, `\def\newmapsto{\mapstochar\joinrel\kern1.5pt\varrightarrow}` seems to work.